# Nonworking Javascript Timeout events

Tags: javascript, html, css, settimeout

I have created a function that runs after 1.8 million milliseconds (I'm using 1.8 seconds for test purposes), but the timeout I'm using never seems to work - even though it's exactly the same one I've used for every other web app/site I've made, ever.

Core code:

```
setTimeout(Test, 10);

var Test = function(){
    alert("KEMAH");
};
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zbMCC/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place the timeout after the function expression.

```
var Test = function(){
    alert("KEMAH");
};
setTimeout(Test, 10);
```

Function expressions (functions assigned to variables) are not "hoisted-up" in the scope. Thus the code executes in the order they appear.

On the otherhand, function declarations are hoisted-up in the scope, so the following code runs perfectly. Notice how the function is declared. Its declared as a function with a name `Test`, instead of having a function assigned to the variable `Test`:

```
//because JavaScript treats function declarations as if they were declared
//UP HERE <--------------.
                       //|
setTimeout(Test, 10);  //|
                       //|
function Test(){ //------'
    alert("KEMAH");
};
```

JavaScript ses your code this way:

1. variable declarations
2. function declarations
3. variable assignments/operations (this is where everything else runs in the order they appear)

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
setTimeout(Test, 10);

function Test(){
    alert("KEMAH");
};
```

or put `var Test = function {...` before use it.

Because the `Test` in `setTimeout` is `undefined` at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can give the function inside

```
setTimeout(function(){
    alert("KEMAH");
}, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

I'm using (in complex scenarios):

```
setInterval("GeneratedFunctionName()", 60000); // 60s
```

Comment: Don't use strings as the first parameter of `setTimeout`/`setInterval` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout